# Arrowed lines for tablature bends in MusiXTeX

Tags: arrows, line, musixtex, arrow-curve

How can I insert arrowed curved lines to indicate bends in tablatures like these ones in MusiXTeX? The documentation says nothing about that.

[image]

Comment: The musixtab package does not provide for those bends (does not provide for the "release" part at all). I can't program in LaTeX (don't have time to try), but I think within the tikz package you would need a macro for a curve with four parameters: starting point (roff of note or, for a release, of the end of the lift which then, as far as I can see, could have always the same starting hight), one controle point, an ending point (\loff of note or somewhere in between notes for a lift, which then can always have the same hight as ending point) and text (above the arrow point, at a fixed hight).

Comment: @C.Peters Yes, I already have implemented something with Tikz, but it would be great the feature to be integrated in future versions.

Comment: Could you add an example to your question (not as answer, but editing your question)? I am interested in how you solved it. Indeed, it would be nice if the MusiXTeX packaged would be extended with this kind of features.